# Why won't the Premiere CS6 timeline playback after edits?

Tags: premiere, playback, cs6

After starting Premiere, playback works fine, but if I edit the timeline and move the current time indicator, the program display either goes dark or gets stuck on a frame and will not play. 
[image]
[image]

I have 12 GB of memory but Premiere never uses more than 4 GB, however when editing it uses 100% CPU. This is an Asus laptop with a 5th generation low voltage Core i7-5500 processor, and Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 and NVIDIA GeForce 840M graphics cards. What can I do to fix this problem? This is a much better spec laptop than my old one and I've never had anything like this happen before.

Comment: I had issues similar to this which I tracked down to a memory issue with a prores codec. I had 16GB and when I went to 32GB the the issue stopped. Are you using third-party prores codec?

Comment: You might try transcoding several of your clips into DNxHD in a fresh project and see if the issue goes away. QT on PC is 32bit only.

Comment: What is the codec of your source video? Do you have hardware acceleration (Mercury Playback Engine) turned on in Premiere?